# What is the equivalent of 'yearweek' function in BigQuery standard SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'll need to extract exactly the "yearweek" of different dates in my table but I couldn't find any match for 'yearweek' in BigQuery (Standard SQL / Legacy SQL ).

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For the result as a string, use `'%Y%W'` with "format".  For example:

```
select format_date('%Y%W', current_date)
```

Comment: Thanks! This just inspired to write my query :)

Comment: @helloworld check out the [format elements table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date) for documentation on these and other format specifiers.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise the following:

```sql
select format_date('%G-%V', your_date)
```

This follows the ISO-8601 standard of numbering weeks that can cross year boundaries. This ISO standard is implemented in Bigquery with `%G` being the year and `%V` being the week.

The answer of @ornachshon is correct (if you drop the dash from my code you get equivalent output), but a bit convoluted. The answer of @gordon-linoff is incorrect, since it will split weeks at the start/end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL:

```
   select 
   concat(EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM current_date), EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM current_date))
```